# Issue in parsing JSON when special characters are included

Tags: apex, json

I have a Json file which has some special character as below:-

```
{
    "TXT1": "Tést Data",
    "TXT2": "can®."
},
```

The Special character (é.®) gives me a error **BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string** while parsing

The Following is my Apex class:-

```
List<Document> d = [Select body, bodyLength, ContentType, Url from Document where DeveloperName ='Json_File'];

if(d.size()>0) {
    Blob b =  d[0].body;
    jsonStr = b.toString();  
}

JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonStr);
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to ensure that the text file that is uploaded to the Document is in UTF-8 format. Google to find editors and tools that are good at that. Then the Apex code should just work.

Comment: when i save the file as UTF-8 format, it gives me the error as System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('' (code 65279 / 0xfeff)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]

Comment: Sounds like you've got the UTF-8 encoding corrected, but you have a "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE" character in the text. While this doesn't display so makes the JSON appear OK, it is not syntactically valid in JSON. It appears to be at the beginning of your file so you could remove it by deleting the first few characters and retyping them (and then re-uploading the file). But there may also be instances further down in the file.

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 without BOM worked for me. Thanks Keith for your helpful response

Comment: @KeithC You should put this into an answer, would be helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using same json file document mentioned by you, the only change that i did is iterating the Json String. Please see the below code.

It works.

```
   try{

        List<Document> docList = [Select Id,Type,body, bodyLength, ContentType, Url from Document WHERE ID='01528000003FqHJAA0'];

        String jsonStr='';
        if(docList.size()>0)
        {
            Blob b =  docList[0].body;
            jsonStr = b.toString();  
        }

        Map<String,Object> mapObj = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonStr);
        for (String key : mapObj.keySet()){
            System.debug('KEY :' + key);
            System.debug('Value :' + mapObj.get(key));
        }

    }catch(Exception exe){
        System.debug('EEROR OCCURED : '+exe.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escape sequence \u with hex value corresponding to special char ?

\u followed by four-hex-digits

Comment: Can you share some code snippet...?

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link for more help for escape special characters

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string